# Adding USB charging port to trimmer, question about voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, usb, usb-c

I'm fairly unexperienced with electronics, but I'm currently working on what should be a relativly easy project, but I have a few questions and maybe you can help me. I recently found an old beard trimmer that didn't work anymore because the battery was weak. So I ordered a new 1.2V battery and solder it to where the old battey was.

Than I thought "Maybe I could add a USB C port for charging". I looked at the power supply and it said 3V DC (150mA. So I ordered a USB port and a part that converts the voltage to 3.3V. After I got the parts and started assembling my project I used my multimeter to check everything and realized that the power supply actually outputs 5V.
So my questions are:

Is the label wrong or is my measurement wrong?

Should I stick with my 3V or should I use the 5V I get directly from the USB port?

Am I missing something else? (like is it okay to use 3.3V when the power supply only has 3V?)

I hope someone can help me because again, I know very little about electronics. Thanks.

PS: here is an image from the inside of my trimmer:

[image: Inside of my beard trimmer]

Comment: At low enough current, the voltage does not really matter as long as it is >1.45 V, although it's wasteful. What series resistance do you have in the circuit? The faster you are trying to charge, the more important the unloaded/open circuit voltage will be. Even better would of course be a 5 V input dedicated single cell NiMH charger IC. BQ24401 springs to mind...

Comment: Which parts you bought and how you wired them? Perhaps there are some mistakes somewhere.

Comment: @Justme I bought a standart usb c female port ad a Arceli AMS1117-3.3 voltage regulator. I'm actually fairly convident that I wired everything correctly. I conected the ports Vbus to the regulators Vin, GND to GND, and then connected Vout to the positive of the old charging port and GND to the negative.

Comment: @winny  There are two resitors in there. The postive pole of the charging port is connected to the positive pole of the battery via a black component labeled N5M and a 10 Ohm resistor. There is also a 30 Ohm Resistor, but I think thats just for the LED.

Comment: So no capacitors at the regulator pins? That is a mistake that might make the regulator unstable and it might now be an oscillator instead of a regulator. Also if it is a USB-C connector, you need configuration resistors so the other device knows that your device is connected.

Comment: @justme oh my mistake. There are capacitors and a 1kOhm resistor on the board with the regulator. Sorry I considered the whole board the regulator. The usb port and the regulator work fine. I measure exactly the 3.3V that I'm expecting. What worries me is that I'm measuring 5V from the original power supply of the beard trimmer (which is not usb), even though it's labeled as 3V.

Comment: Try to trace out the full circuit, make a schematic based on the things you know. If there is an IC on the board hat you do not know its purpose, just add a black box on the schematic with any of the labels you see on the device. Also try to measure the voltage from the charger when it is actually charging the battery